# Working off the Quote in Visualforce, how can I access Contacts? Getting an unsupported complex expression error

Tags: visualforce, related-list, relationships, aggregate

The quote is associated with an account, and the account has contacts.  I can access the account data just fine, but when I try to display any contact data then it fails with the following error:

> Error: Aggregate Relationship is used in an unsupported complex
>   expression containing 'Account.contacts'

Here is a simple example that will replicate this error.

```
<apex:page standardController="Quote" renderAs="PDF">
...
    <apex:repeat value="{!quote.account.Contacts}" var="item">
        <apex:outputField value="{!item.Name}"/>
    </apex:repeat>
...
```

Does anyone know how I can access my Contact data?  Note that we are using Salesforce professional edition, so Apex is off the table.  Thanks for helping!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think that the only way to do this is through `<apex:iframe>` and a second page.

Page1:

```
  <apex:page standardController="Quote">
      <apex:iframe src="/apex/Page2?id={!Quote.Account}"/>
  <apex:page>
```

Page2:

```
 <apex:page standardController="Account" showheader="false" sidebar="false">
      <apex:repeat value="{!Account.Contacts}" var="item">
           <apex:outputField value="{!item.Name}"/>
      </apex:repeat>
 <apex:page>
```

Comment: Thanks for the feedback.  Unfortunately this doesn't appear to work when the page is rendered as a PDF.  I will wait a day or 2 to see if there are any alternatives that work for the PDF case and if not, then I plan to accept your answer.

Comment: Of course,  thank you. I'm sorry that this hasn't solved your particular problem.